# How to get a localized version of CLSID_StockColorPage?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, localization, activex, atl

When I created an ATL ActiveX control with property pages I used CLSID_StockColorPage to add an universal "Color" property page, but it is not localized (English always). Is there a way to use at least a system language?

Same with CLSID_StockPicturePage and CLSID_StockFontPage.

Comment: If possible at all, it might need you to manage thread locale (with `SetThreadLocale` and friends) to affect property page's load of resources.

Comment: Both SetThreadLocale() and setlocale() has no effect. A properties pages dialog created by OleCreatePropertyFrame() call also has a LCID parameter but it using is a recommended option, not a required.